# Vue: Set user in vuex store before registration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex

Hi Stackoverflow Community,

I have a Vue.js application where a user can register. The registration is displayed in three different components. Register 1 (email, password), Register 2 (personal information) and Register 3 (preferences).

I implemented an api post request after the user press register on the first page according to bezkoder: https://www.bezkoder.com/vue-3-authentication-jwt/

What I am trying to do now is instead of register the user directly, I want to save the user data in my vuex store and send the api post request in Register 3 instead of Register 1, when I have all the user information.

Unfortunately, I am not able to create a new state in my store. This is my auth.module.js Code (store):

```
import AuthService from "../services/auth.service";
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

const initialState = user
  ? { status: { loggedIn: true }, user }
  : { status: { loggedIn: false }, user: null };

export const auth = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState,

  actions: {
    login({ commit }, user) {
      return AuthService.login(user).then(
        (user) => {
          commit("loginSuccess", user);
          return Promise.resolve(user);
        },
        (error) => {
          commit("loginFailure");
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    },
    logout({ commit }) {
      AuthService.logout();
      commit("logout");
    },
    register({ commit }, user) {
      return AuthService.register(user).then(
        (response) => {
          commit("registerSuccess");
          return Promise.resolve(response.data);
        },
        (error) => {
          commit("registerFailure");
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    loginSuccess(state, user) {
      state.status.loggedIn = true;
      state.user = user;
    },
    loginFailure(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
    registerSuccess(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = true;
    },
    registerFailure(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
    },
  },
};
```

So I need to create a state for my userdata (email, password, preferences) and then an action and a method to save my userdata from Register 1 and 2.

Does someone has a clue how I could implement this? Or do you have a better idea how to create my registration?

Glad for all your tips and tricks :)

Comment: you just need to create state object and put all user information in that object. For example, state: { email: "", password: "", name: "" .... }

Comment: @AliBabaAzimi somehow I can't create a new state in my auth.module.js File....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix it. I created a new file named "patient.module.js" and there I could set the states. My code is the following:

```
export const patient = {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    email: null,
    password: null,
    location: [],
    specialty: [],
    attribute: [],
    language: [],
    gender: [],
  },
  actions: {
    register({ commit }, patient) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        commit("setPatientData", patient);
        resolve();
      });
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setPatientData(state, patient) {
      Object.assign(state, patient);
    },
  },
};
```